# Regex for multiple app versions

Tags: regex, powershell

Im trying to get list of versions from my custom attribute in **powershell** script. Atrribute looks like this:

`[assembly: CompatibleVersions("1.7.1.0","1.7.1.1","1.2.2.3")]`

And I end up with regex like this but it does'nt work at all:

`'\(\"([^\",?]*)\"+\)'`

Comment: try this `((\d+\.){2,3}\d)`

Comment: You can do that even without  a regex, but I guess you just can use `Regex.Matches(s, "\"([^\"]+)\"").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value).ToList()`

Comment: I forgot to add that Im looking for it in powershell script sorry.

Comment: or try this \(\"([0-9.,\"]*)\"\)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this as a two-step process: First you parse out the `CompatibleVersions` attribute, and then you split out those version numbers. Otherwise you will have difficulties finding the version numbers individually without likely finding otheer version-like numbers.

```
$s = '[assembly: CompatibleVersions("1.7.1.0","1.7.1.1","1.2.2.3")]'
$versions = ($s | Select-String -Pattern 'CompatibleVersions\(([^)]+)\)' | % { $_.Matches }).Groups[1].Value
$versions.Split(',') | % { $_.Trim('"') } | Write-Host
# 1.7.1.0
# 1.7.1.1
# 1.2.2.3
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
$s | select-string -pattern "\d+(?:\.\d+)+" -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | ForEach-Object {$_.Value}
```

The `\d+(?:\.\d+)+` pattern will match:

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)+` - 1 or more sequences of a `.` and 1+ digits.

[image]

See the [**regex demo on RegexStorm**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%2B&i=%5Bassembly%3A%20CompatibleVersions%28%221.7.1.0%22%2C%221.7.1.1%22%2C%221.2.2.3%22%29%5D).

Answer (score 2):

Start by grabbing the parentheses pair and everything inside:

```
$string = '[assembly: CompatibleVersions("1.7.1.0","1.7.1.1","1.2.2.3")]'
if($string -match '\(([^)]+)\)'){
    # Remove the parentheses themselves, split by comma and then trim the "
    $versionList = $Matches[0].Trim("()") -split ',' |ForEach-Object Trim '"'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`'"([.\d]+)"'` will match any substring composed of dots and digits (`\d`) and comprised into double quotes (")

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/lh4cv1/1)

Comment: Even worse - of ANY symbols and digits :-). But your message should be a comment. Wait a bit till you can comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

A number between .. can be 0, but cannot be 00, 01 or similar.

Pay attention to the starting [

This is a regex for the check:

```
^\[assembly: CompatibleVersions\("(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d*|0)){3}"(?:,"(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d*|0)){3}")*\)]$
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/wEcCk3/2) is the regex with tests.

But if you are reading a list, you should use instead:

```
^\[assembly: CompatibleVersions\("((?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d*|0)){3}"(?:,"(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d*|0)){3}")*)\)]$
```

By it you will extract the "...","..."... consequence from the inner parenthesis.

After that split the result string by '","' into a list and remove last " from the last element and the first " from the first element. Now you have list of correct versions Strings.

Alas, regex cannot create a list without split() function.